# Firebase Translate Text Extension - Is it possible to translate fields in nested collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-translation-api, firebase-extensions

I am using [Firebase Translate Text Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-translate-text) to translate few documents fields in my project. I want to add one more field that is in a documents in the nested collection:
[image]

So each document in collection "spots_test" has collection "reviews". I want to translate one field in each new review added, and I am wondering how can I set up it in Firebase Translate Text Extension, I was trying to set up something like this, but it didn't work:
[image]

Is there any way to handle nested collections?

Comment: Try to add the code that you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find proper documentation, however I experimented a bit. It seems to be working this way on my side (`LevelOne` is collection, `test` is sub-collection in any document of the collection):

**LevelOne/{doc}/test**

I don't think that it's important what is in the brackets I tested `{something}` as well. Working fine.

As this is Firebase Function base feature, I tried the same [wildcards logic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) as in Firebase Function background triggers for Firestore. To be honest, as I didn't found any documentation in extension [docs](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/next/firestore-translate-text) so I am not sure if this is intended behavior, but it works.

UPDATE:

I have continued the test. The extension is generating function visible in Functions tab of Firebase console. The trigger is visible there. The value of the trigger is gendered from extension configuration "Collection path"+`{messageId}`. So for example you can setup:

**{collection}/{doc}/{subcollection}**

In this situation translate text extension will work on every document in 2nd level collection no matter what the path is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that there are wildcards in the firestore. Postawię Ci piwo jak otworzą Starą Zajezdnie czy jakieś inne knajpy w Krk :D

Comment: ohh, choc aktualnie nie popijam, to jak sie skonczy, to się z chęciął, k urwał, napije!

Comment: How can we configure Translate Text to work with a subcollection of a subcollection? The following does not seem to work:
posts/{post}/responses/{response}/replies

Comment: Well, it wasn't working; wasn't translating the documents I was creating through my app. After manually creating a document in the firebase dashboard to troubleshoot, it 'sprang to life' and started translating the documents.